# PYMC Water Demand Forecasting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, bayesian, pymc

I am working on making a water demand forecasting model that takes into account time and meteorological conditions. I am new to this and struggling to generate a forecast array. Ideally it would take into account the previous years water demand+meteorological conditions+time, and then use current time and meteorological conditions to generate a forecast for the demand.

Here is my code, the graph that displays doesn't mean much for forecasting

```
import pymc as pm
import scipy
from scipy import stats, signal
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pymc import Normal, Dirichlet, Categorical, Gamma, deterministic, MCMC, Matplot, Poisson, graph, Exponential, DiscreteUniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load data into the code
value_array2013=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\2013 Effluent flow Value.csv', delimiter=',')
value_array2014=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\2014 Effluent flow Value.csv', delimiter=',')
time_array2013=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\Time 2013.csv', delimiter=',')
time_array2014=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\Time 2014.csv', delimiter=',')
hourly=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\24hr time 2014.csv', delimiter=',')
dtemp2014=np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data 4 python\\corrected temp K.csv', delimiter=',')

#make prior distirbution
n=np.random.normal(size=len(time_array2014))

#make likelihood(tau)--> uninformed
tau=pm.Gamma('tau',alpha=0.1, beta=0.1)

#max temp and max time
j=305.3
h=365

#making demand equation that uses the previous value and %change in time and temp
demandd=np.zeros(len(time_array2014))
for i in range(0,len(time_array2014)):
    demandd[i]=demandd[i-1]+demandd[i-1]*((dtemp2014[i]-dtemp2014[i-1])/j)+demandd[i-1]*((time_array2014[i]-time_array2014[i-1])/h)

#demand + random variable will give actual demand
y=demandd+n

#observed variable to test y against
@pm.observed
@pm.stochastic(plot=False)
def demand (value=value_array2014,mu=y,tau=n):
    return pm.lognormal_like(value,mu,tau)

#specify the model
model=pm.Model({'y':y,'tau':tau,'n':n})

#instantiate MCMC
mcmc=pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(iter=10000, burn=1000)


#forecast
plt.scatter(time_array2014,y)
plt.show()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear from what you have posted what is not working. Can you clarify? A couple of observations: you don't have to use `@stochastic` when you use `@observed`; that is redundant. Also, we have a `Lognormal` object in PyMC, so you don't have to write your own. You say `n` is a prior distribution, but it is just a random sample from a normal distribution. You also do not need to make a `Model` object, because `MCMC` is a subclass. HTH.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks so much for getting back to me. I adjusted 'n' to be a normal distribution and used PYMC Lognormal object. When I run the code it says in my observed component "the value of the parents is forbidding the current value". Does that mean the equation I have supplied is inaccurate, or did I write it incorrectly?

Comment: It means the initial value is not within the support of the distribution. Try specifying different initial values.